# The 'python_digest' package could not be imported

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Here is my api resource class.

**api.py**

```
class UserTypeResource( ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = UserType.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user_types'
        authorization=MyAuthorization()
        authentication=DigestAuthentication()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri=False
        limit=0
```

And i got this error when I calling the api.

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/user_type
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:The 'python_digest' package could not be imported. It is required for use with the 'DigestAuthentication' class.
```

**How should I correct this one ?**

Comment: Have you installed `python-digest` (`pip install python-digest`)? It is optional and does not get automatically installed with Tastypie.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks, I thought that package has already available in Tastypie.